# CLI app to spin up a Docker cluster

Tags: beginner, go, docker

This is my first Go project.  I've written a CLI app to provision a database cluster on docker containers. Since it's a distributed database, you can configure per-node services.  For example: to configure a 3-node cluster (version 7.1.4) with kv on node1, query/index on node2, and analytics on node3, run the following:

```
 ./cluster -v 7.1.4 -s n0:kv,n1:n1ql+index,n2:cbas
```

---

```
// main.go
package main

import (
    "bytes"
    "fmt"
    "log"
    "net/http"
    "os"
    "os/exec"
    "regexp"
    "strings"

    flag "github.com/spf13/pflag"
)

func main() {
    log.SetFlags(0)

    _, err: = exec.LookPath("docker")
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatal("Please install docker.  Go to https://docs.docker.com/engine/install/")
    }

    makeDockerNetwork()

    // TODO:  support other linux OS besides ubuntu 20 for internal build
    // TODO:  support arm arch
    version: = flag.StringP("version", "v", "", "CBS version")
    noinit: = flag.Bool("noinit", false, "Do not initialize node")
    services: = flag.StringP("services", "s", "", "Per node services")
    indexStorage: = flag.StringP("index", "i", "plasma", "Index storage mode - plasma, memory_optimized")
    username: = flag.StringP("username", "u", "admin", "Administrator username")
    password: = flag.StringP("password", "p", "password", "Administrator password")
    sampleBucket: = flag.StringP("bucket", "b", "", "Load sample bucket")

    flag.Parse()
    allNodeServices: = [] string {}

    if *version == "" {
        log.Fatal("Please provide CBS version")
    } else {
        re: = regexp.MustCompile(`^(\d\.\d\.\d)-(\d{4,5})$`)
        if re.MatchString(*version) {
            matches: = re.FindStringSubmatch(*version)
            buildImage(matches[1], matches[2])
        }
    }

    if !*noinit {
        if *services == "" {
            log.Fatal("Please specify per node services")
        } else {
            nodeServiceTuples: = strings.Split(*services, ",")

            for _, t: = range nodeServiceTuples {
                services: = strings.Replace(strings.Split(t, ":")[1], "+", ",", -1)
                allNodeServices = append(allNodeServices, services)
            }
        }
    }

    port: = getNextPort()
    name: = randomName()
    makeNode(port, name + "0", *version)
    waitTillNodeIsUp(port)

    if *noinit {
        os.Exit(0)
    }

    initFirstNode(port, allNodeServices[0], *username, *password, *indexStorage)

    // Provision other nodes
    if len(allNodeServices) > 1 {
        IP: = getIP(name + "0")
        allNodeStrings: = fmt.Sprintf("ns_1@%s,", IP)

        for nodePort, i := port + 1, 1; i < len(allNodeServices); i, nodePort = i + 1, nodePort + 1 {
            nodeServices: = allNodeServices[i]
            nodeString: = addNode(port, nodePort, fmt.Sprintf("%s%d", name, i), *version, nodeServices, *username, *password)
            allNodeStrings += nodeString
        }

        rebalance(port, allNodeStrings, *username, *password)
    }

    if *sampleBucket != "" {
        httpDo(http.MethodPost,
            fmt.Sprintf("http://localhost:%d/sampleBuckets/install", port),
            bytes.NewBufferString(fmt.Sprintf("[\"%s\"]", *sampleBucket)),
            Options {
                user: *username,
                pass: *password,
                errorMessage: "install sample bucket failed",
                status: http.StatusAccepted,
            },
        )
    }

    log.Printf("First node of cluster - %s - is ready on port %d\n", name + "0", port)
}
```

```
// cluster.go
package main

import (
    "bytes"
    "encoding/json"
    "fmt"
    "io"
    "log"
    "net/http"
    "net/url"
    "os/exec"
    "strings"
    "time"
)

const (
    MAX_TRIES = 120
)

type Options struct {
    user, pass, errorMessage string
    status int
}

func httpDo(method, uri string, data *bytes.Buffer, opt Options)[] byte {
    // cleanup before panic
    defer func() {
        if p: = recover();
        p != nil {
            cleanupContainers()
            panic(p)
        }
    }()

    client: = & http.Client {}
    req, err: = http.NewRequest(method, uri, data)

    if err != nil {
        cleanupContainers()
        log.Fatalf("%s\nNewRequest failed for %+v: %v", opt.errorMessage, req, err)
    }

    req.Header.Add("Content-Type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded")

    if opt.user != "" && opt.pass != "" {
        req.SetBasicAuth(opt.user, opt.pass)
    }

    req.Close = true
    resp, err: = client.Do(req)
    if err != nil {
        cleanupContainers()
        log.Fatalf("%s\nsend request failed %+v: %v", opt.errorMessage, req, err)
    }

    defer resp.Body.Close()
    respBody, err: = io.ReadAll(resp.Body)
    if err != nil {
        cleanupContainers()
        log.Fatalf("%s\ncould not read resp body for request %+v: %v", opt.errorMessage, req, err)
    }

    if resp.StatusCode != opt.status {
        rb, err: = req.GetBody()
        if err != nil {
            cleanupContainers()
            log.Fatalf("%s\ncould not get req body for request %+v: %v", opt.errorMessage, req, err)
        }
        reqBody, err: = io.ReadAll(rb)
        if err != nil {
            cleanupContainers()
            log.Fatalf("%s\ncould not read req body for request %+v: %v", opt.errorMessage, req, err)
        }

        cleanupContainers()
        log.Fatalf("%s\n%+v\nreqBody: %s\n%+v\nrespBody: %s", opt.errorMessage, req, string(reqBody), resp, string(respBody))
    }

    return respBody
}

func makeNode(port int, containerName string, version string) {
    cmd: = exec.Command(
        "docker", "run", "--rm", "-d",
        "-p", fmt.Sprintf("%d:8091", port),
        "-p", "8092-8096",
        "-p", "11207",
        "-p", "11210",
        "-p", "18091-18096",
        "--name", containerName,
        "--privileged",
        "--network=cb-net",
        fmt.Sprintf("couchbase/server:%s", version),
    )
    if err: = cmd.Run();err != nil {
        log.Fatalf("could not create node: %v", err)
    }

    runningContainers = append(runningContainers, containerName)
}

func waitTillNodeIsUp(port int) {
    url: = fmt.Sprintf("http://localhost:%d", port)

    for tries: = 1;tries <= MAX_TRIES;tries++{
        resp, err: = http.Get(url)
        if resp != nil && err != nil {
            log.Printf("HTTP GET for waitTillNodeIsUp failed: %v", err)
            time.Sleep(1 * time.Second)
            continue
        }

        if resp != nil && resp.StatusCode == http.StatusOK {
            return
        }

        time.Sleep(1 * time.Second)
    }

    cleanupContainers()
    log.Fatal("node is not up in 2 min")
}

func initFirstNode(port int, services, username, password, storageMode string) {
    httpDo(http.MethodPost,
        fmt.Sprintf("http://localhost:%d/settings/indexes", port),
        bytes.NewBufferString(url.Values {
            "storageMode": {
                storageMode
            }
        }.Encode()),
        Options {
            errorMessage: "Index configuration failed",
            status: http.StatusOK,
        },
    )

    httpDo(http.MethodPost,
        fmt.Sprintf("http://localhost:%d/node/controller/setupServices", port),
        bytes.NewBufferString(url.Values {
            "services": {
                services
            }
        }.Encode()),
        Options {
            errorMessage: "Setting up services failed",
            status: http.StatusOK,
        },
    )

    httpDo(http.MethodPost,
        fmt.Sprintf("http://localhost:%d/settings/web", port),
        bytes.NewBufferString(url.Values {
            "username": {
                username
            },
            "password": {
                password
            },
            "port": {
                "8091"
            }
        }.Encode()),
        Options {
            errorMessage: "Setting up username and password failed",
            status: http.StatusOK,
        },
    )

    // Set memory quotas
    // n1ql and backup don't have quotas
    form: = url.Values {}
    form.Add("memoryQuota", "256")
    form.Add("indexMemoryQuota", "256")
    form.Add("cbasMemoryQuota", "1024")
    form.Add("eventingMemoryQuota", "256")
    form.Add("ftsMemoryQuota", "256")

    httpDo(http.MethodPost,
        fmt.Sprintf("http://localhost:%d/pools/default", port),
        bytes.NewBufferString(form.Encode()),
        Options {
            user: username,
            pass: password,
            errorMessage: "Setting up memory quotas failed",
            status: http.StatusOK,
        },
    )
}

func addNode(port, nodePort int, hostname, version, services, username, password string) string {
    makeNode(nodePort, hostname, version)
    waitTillNodeIsUp(nodePort)
    IP: = getIP(hostname)

    form: = url.Values {}
    form.Add("hostname", IP)
    form.Add("user", username)
    form.Add("password", password)
    form.Add("services", services)

    httpDo(http.MethodPost,
        fmt.Sprintf("http://localhost:%d/controller/addNode", port),
        bytes.NewBufferString(form.Encode()),
        Options {
            user: username,
            pass: password,
            errorMessage: "Add node failed",
            status: http.StatusOK,
        },
    )

    return fmt.Sprintf("ns_1@%s,", IP)
}

func rebalance(port int, knownNodes, username, password string) {
    nodes: = url.QueryEscape(strings.TrimSuffix(knownNodes, ","))
    form: = url.Values {}
    form.Add("knownNodes", nodes)

    httpDo(http.MethodPost,
        fmt.Sprintf("http://localhost:%d/controller/rebalance", port),
        bytes.NewBufferString(strings.ReplaceAll(form.Encode(), "%25", "%")),
        Options {
            user: username,
            pass: password,
            errorMessage: "Rebalance failed",
            status: http.StatusOK,
        },
    )

    for tries: = 1;tries <= MAX_TRIES;tries++{
        body: = httpDo(http.MethodGet,
            fmt.Sprintf("http://localhost:%d/pools/default/rebalanceProgress", port),
            bytes.NewBufferString(""),
            Options {
                user: username,
                pass: password,
                errorMessage: "Could not get rebalance progress",
                status: http.StatusOK,
            },
        )

            progress: = struct {
            Status string `json:"status"`
        } {}

            if err: = json.NewDecoder(strings.NewReader(string(body))).Decode( & progress);err != nil {
            cleanupContainers()
            log.Fatalf("Could not decode rebalance progress: %v", err)
        }

        if progress.Status == "none" {
            return
        }

        time.Sleep(1 * time.Second)
    }

    cleanupContainers()
    log.Fatal("Could not rebalance in 2 min")
}
```

```
// misc.go
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "log"
    "math/rand"
    "os/exec"
    "regexp"
    "strconv"
    "strings"
    "time"
)

var (
    runningContainers = [] string {}
)

func randomName() string {
    rand.Seed(time.Now().UnixNano())
    return words[rand.Intn(len(words))]
}

func getNextPort() int {
    out, err: = exec.Command("docker",
        "container",
        "ls",
        "--format",
        "{{.Ports}}",
        "--filter",
        "status=running").Output()
    if err != nil {
        cleanupContainers()
        log.Fatalf("could not list running containers: %v", err)
    }

    lastPort: = 9000
    re: = regexp.MustCompile(`:9\d{3}`)
    for _, line: = range strings.Split(string(out), "\n") {
        matches: = re.FindStringSubmatch(line)
        if len(matches) > 0 {
            port, err: = strconv.Atoi(matches[0][1: ])
            if err != nil {
                continue // silently ignore error
            }
            if port > lastPort {
                lastPort = port
            }
        }
    }

    return lastPort + 1
}

func getIP(containerID string) string {
    out, err: = exec.Command("docker",
        "inspect",
        "-f",
        "{{range .NetworkSettings.Networks}}{{.IPAddress}}{{end}}", containerID).Output()

    if err != nil {
        cleanupContainers()
        log.Fatalf("could not get IP of container %s: %v", containerID, err)
    }

    return fmt.Sprint(strings.TrimSpace(string(out)))
}

// if network cb-net does not exist, create it
func makeDockerNetwork() {
    cmd: = exec.Command("docker", "network", "inspect", "cb-net")

    if err: = cmd.Run();err != nil {
        cmd: = exec.Command("docker", "network", "create", "cb-net")

        if err: = cmd.Run();err != nil {
            log.Fatalf("could not create docker network cb-net: %v", err)
        }

        log.Println("created docker network cb-net")
    }
}

func cleanupContainers() {
        containers: = strings.Join(runningContainers[: ], " ")
        cmd: = exec.Command(
            "docker",
            "stop",
            containers,
        )

        if err: = cmd.Run();err != nil {
            log.Fatalf("could not remove containers %s:\n%v", containers, err)
        }
   }
```

```
// internal_build.go
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "io"
    "log"
    "os"
    "os/exec"
    "strings"
    "text/template"
)

func buildImage(version, build string) {
    output, err: = exec.Command("docker", "image", "ls").Output()
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatalf("could not list docker images: %s", err)
    }

    tempFile, err: = os.CreateTemp("/tmp/", "docker.file.*")
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatalf("could not create temp file: %s", err)
    }
    defer os.Remove(tempFile.Name())

    if !strings.Contains(string(output), "couchbase/server") || !strings.Contains(string(output), fmt.Sprintf("%s-%s", version, build)) {
        writeDockerfile(version, build, tempFile)
        cmd: = exec.Command("docker", "build", ".", "-f", tempFile.Name(), "-t", fmt.Sprintf("couchbase/server:%s-%s", version, build))
        stderr, err: = cmd.StderrPipe()
        if err != nil {
            log.Fatalf("could not build docker image: %s", err)
        }

        if err: = cmd.Start();
        err != nil {
            log.Fatalf("could not build docker image: %s", err)
        }

        errMessage, err: = io.ReadAll(stderr)
        if err != nil {
            log.Fatalf("could not build docker image: %s", err)
        }
        log.Println(string(errMessage))

        if err: = cmd.Wait();
        err != nil {
            log.Fatalf("could not build docker image: %s", err)
        }

    }
}

func writeDockerfile(version, buildNum string, file * os.File) {
    vars: = struct {
        Package string
        URL string
    } {
        Package: fmt.Sprintf("couchbase-server-enterprise_%s-%s-ubuntu20.04_amd64.deb", version, buildNum),
        URL: fmt.Sprintf("http://builds.com/%s/%s", version, buildNum),
    }

        const dockerFile = `
    FROM ubuntu:20.04
    
    ENV PATH=$PATH:/opt/couchbase/bin:/opt/couchbase/bin/tools:/opt/couchbase/bin/install
    
    RUN set -x && \
        apt-get update && \
        apt-get install -yq runit wget chrpath tzdata \
        lsof lshw sysstat net-tools numactl bzip2 libtinfo5 && \
        apt-get autoremove && apt-get clean && \
        rm -rf /var/lib/apt/lists/* /tmp/* /var/tmp/*
    
    RUN if [ ! -x /usr/sbin/runsvdir-start ]; then \
            cp -a /etc/runit/2 /usr/sbin/runsvdir-start; \
        fi
    
    RUN groupadd -g 1000 couchbase && useradd couchbase -u 1000 -g couchbase -M
    
    RUN set -x && \
        export INSTALL_DONT_START_SERVER=1 && \
        wget {{.URL}}/{{.Package}} && \
        apt install -y ./{{.Package}} && \
        rm -f ./{{.Package}} && \
        apt-get autoremove && apt-get clean && \
        rm -rf /var/lib/apt/lists/* /tmp/* /var/tmp/*
    
    RUN mkdir -p /etc/service/couchbase-server/
    
    RUN printf "#!/bin/sh \n\
    exec 2>&1 \n\
    cd /opt/couchbase \n\
    mkdir -p var/lib/couchbase \n\
    var/lib/couchbase/config \n\
    var/lib/couchbase/data \n\
    var/lib/couchbase/stats \n\
    var/lib/couchbase/logs \n\
    var/lib/moxi \n\
    \n\
    chown -R couchbase:couchbase var \n\
    if [ \"\$(whoami)\" = \"couchbase\" ]; then \n\
    exec /opt/couchbase/bin/couchbase-server -- -kernel global_enable_tracing false -noinput \n\
    else \n\
    exec chpst -ucouchbase  /opt/couchbase/bin/couchbase-server -- -kernel global_enable_tracing false -noinput \n\
    fi" > /etc/service/couchbase-server/run
    
    RUN chmod a+x /etc/service/couchbase-server/run
    RUN chown -R couchbase:couchbase /etc/service
    
    RUN mkdir -p /etc/runit/runsvdir/default/couchbase-server/supervise \
        && chown -R couchbase:couchbase \
                    /etc/service \
                    /etc/runit/runsvdir/default/couchbase-server/supervise
    
    RUN printf "#!/bin/sh \
    echo \"Running in Docker container - $0 not available\"" > /usr/local/bin/dummy.sh
    
    RUN chmod a+x /usr/local/bin/dummy.sh
    
    RUN ln -s dummy.sh /usr/local/bin/iptables-save && \
        ln -s dummy.sh /usr/local/bin/lvdisplay && \
        ln -s dummy.sh /usr/local/bin/vgdisplay && \
        ln -s dummy.sh /usr/local/bin/pvdisplay 
    
    RUN printf "#!/bin/bash \n\
    set -e \n\
    \
    staticConfigFile=/opt/couchbase/etc/couchbase/static_config \n\
    restPortValue=8091 \n\
    function overridePort() { \n\
    portName=\$1 \n\
portNameUpper=\$(echo \$portName | awk '{print toupper(\$0)}') \n\
portValue=\${!portNameUpper} \n\
    if [ \"\$portValue\" != \"\" ]; then \n\
if grep -Fq \"{\${portName},\" \${staticConfigFile} \n\
then \n\
echo \"Don't override port \${portName} because already available in \$staticConfigFile\" \n\
else \
echo \"Override port '\$portName' with value '\$portValue'\" \n\
echo \"{\$portName, \$portValue}.\" >> \${staticConfigFile} \n\
\
if [ \${portName} == \"rest_port\" ]; then \n\
restPortValue=\${portValue} \n\
fi \n\
fi \n\
fi \n\
} \n\
\n\
overridePort \"rest_port\" \n\
overridePort \"mccouch_port\" \n\
overridePort \"memcached_port\" \n\
overridePort \"query_port\" \n\
overridePort \"ssl_query_port\" \n\
overridePort \"fts_http_port\" \n\
overridePort \"moxi_port\" \n\
overridePort \"ssl_rest_port\" \n\
overridePort \"ssl_capi_port\" \n\
overridePort \"ssl_proxy_downstream_port\" \n\
overridePort \"ssl_proxy_upstream_port\" \n\
\n\
[[ \"\$1\" == \"couchbase-server\" ]] && { \n\
    \n\
    if [ \"\$(whoami)\" = \"couchbase\" ]; then \n\
\n\
if [ ! -w /opt/couchbase/var -o \n\
\$(find /opt/couchbase/var -maxdepth 0 -printf '%%u') != \"couchbase\" ]; then \n\
    echo \"/opt/couchbase/var is not owned and writable by UID 1000\" \n\
    echo \"Aborting as Couchbase Server will likely not run\" \n\
    exit 1 \n\
    fi \n\
    fi \n\
    echo \"Starting Couchbase Server -- Web UI available at http://ip:\$restPortValue\" \n\
echo \"and logs available in /opt/couchbase/var/lib/couchbase/logs\" \n\
exec /usr/sbin/runsvdir-start \n\ 
} \n\
\n\
exec \"\$@\" "> /entrypoint.sh
    
    RUN chmod a+x /entrypoint.sh
    ENTRYPOINT ["/entrypoint.sh"]
    CMD ["couchbase-server"]
    `

        tmpl,
    err: = template.New("internal").Parse(dockerFile)
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatalf("could not create template: %s", err)
    }

    err = tmpl.Execute(file, vars)
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatalf("could not execute template: %s", err)
    }

}
```

````
 // words.go
 package main

 var words = [...] string {
     "amber",
     "apron",
     "arise",
     "beach",
     "beard",
     "beast",
     "blaze",
     "blend",
     "bless",
     "bloom",
     "bonus",
     "braid",
     "brick",
     "brush",
     "bumpy",
     "bunny",
     "chaos",
     "chart",
     "chess",
     "chill",
     "choir",
     "clerk",
     "coast",
     "comet",
     "coral",
     "crate",
     "crisp",
     "ditch",
     "drown",
     "equip",
     "erase",
     "evoke",
     "feast",
     "fever",
     "flame",
     "flute",
     "forge",
     "glide",
     "globe",
     "grape",
     "jeans",
     "juice",
     "lemon",
     "lodge",
     "logic",
     "magic",
     "march",
     "opera",
     "panda",
     "panic",
     "plump",
     "pride",
     "prize",
     "proof",
     "proud",
     "quota",
     "radar",
     "ridge",
     "rifle",
     "route",
     "sable",
     "salad",
     "scoop",
     "seize",
     "shame",
     "shine",
     "sloth",
     "smile",
     "spade",
     "spark",
     "spike",
     "spoil",
     "sport",
     "spray",
     "stall",
     "straw",
     "swamp",
     "swarm",
     "sweep",
     "swing",
     "thick",
     "thigh",
     "thorn",
     "thump",
     "tiger",
     "toast",
     "torch",
     "towel",
     "trust",
     "virus",
     "vocal",
     "watch",
     "weave",
     "whale",
     "whisk",
     "wrist",
     "yacht",
 }

```
````

Comment: Please post the entire code in the original post. Links are not permissible; they eventually go stale.

Comment: Removed github link and posted the entire code.